# PostgreSQL on Windows fails to start - 'could not create shared memory segment'

Tags: postgresql, configuration, startup

PostgreSQL 9.4 & 9.5 (beta) on my Windows 7 laptop fails to start. In the Windows event log I see the following error:

> 2015-11-10 13:53:49 IST FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment   "Global/PostgreSQL.851401618": Permission denied

It was working before for a long time, and suddenly it stopped.

I tried to uninstall and install, without any luck.

`dynamic_shared_memory_type` is set to `windows`.

Answer (score 2):

*<sub>Community Wiki answer generated from question comments by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)</sub>*

Try setting `dynamic_shared_memory_type = none` in ***postgresql.conf***.

*"Permission denied"* seems to indicate that the permissions for the user under which the service runs have been changed.